# Updating static text on JasperReport won't compile and gives error

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I had to update a static text; only static text not dynamic, I changed it and generated .jasper but my project wont generate any reports like it use to.

I get this exception. Please Help!!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This hardly looks like a problem with your Label.
Your report looks for a scriptlet with class scriptlet.ReportScriptlet and can't find it. The first thing you should do is make sure you've added the jar file containing said class in your project's build path.
If you have it added to the build path and still won't compile, sometimes JasperSoft Studio doesn't update its cache, throwing errors that don't actually exist.
In such a case, your best course of action would be to restart the process. Make sure you terminate all JasperSoft Studio processes, since they tend to get left behind.